# traffic statistics by roads or parts of any German city

Tags: germany, traffic

I'm looking for any traffic statistics by roads or parts of any German cities. I would like to use it for a QGIS-Workshop with students of Infrastructure-Science.

Add: I found something at DeStatis: https://www.destatis.de/DE/Publikationen/Thematisch/TransportVerkehr/ThemaVerkehr.html but unfortunately without spatial reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [GeoPortal Deutschland](http://www.geoportal.de/EN/Geoportal/Services/Spatial-Data-and-Services-in-Web/_functions/germany/germany_table.html?lang=en) has a list of sources from which to pull GIS data.

A first stop might be [Open Data](https://open.nrw/de/dat_kat)

[Berlin's FIS-Broker](http://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/index.jsp) provides a pretty nice dataset. If you are not German speaking the word you are looking for: Straßenverkehrszählung or Verkehrsmengen.
[image]